# LINQ select a company that is a member of a least one of the selected categories

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of categories (CategoryID's) List categoryIds;
This list contains some id's based on a previous selection made by the user.

Then i have a database with companies that can be a member of one or more categories. 
This is maintained in a join table CompaniesInCategory, which results in an object structure like company.Categories.

Now my question is, how do i select all companies that are at least a member of one of the selected categories.

```
List<int> categoryIds = new List<int>() {123, 3, 5858, 23};    
List<company> companies = (from c in context.Companies
                           where c.Categories.(one of the Id's of these c.Categories should be in the list named categoryIds) 
                           select c);
```

Each company has a list of categories attached to it. And from this list of categories (c.Categories) (which all have a CategoryId) at least one has to match with one of the id's from the list categoryIds.

Comment: maybe `join x in CompaniesInCategory on x.CompanyId equals c.CompanyId`

Comment: Is my answer what you wanted?  It will select all rows from Companies table  that have a Category that is in the categoryIds List()

Comment: No, that doesn't work, because in categoryIds.Contains(c.Categories), categoryIds is a List<int> and c.Categories is a list of Category objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var companies = dc.Companies
    .Where(c => c.Categories.Any(cat => categoryIds.Contains(cat.Id)))
```

*'At least one of'* often translates best into LINQ's `Any()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your are talking about this:

```
var categoryIds=(new[] { 123, 3, 5858, 23 }).ToList();

var category=
    new {
        Id=123
    };

var company=
    new {
        Categories=(new[] { category }).ToList()
    };

var context=
    new {
        Companies=(new[] { company }).ToList()
    };

var companies=(
    from c in context.Companies
    from x in c.Categories
    from y in categoryIds
    where x.Id==y
    select c
    ).ToList();
```

So where you specified:

```
where c.Categories.(one of the Id's of these c.Categories should be in the list named categoryIds)
```

Would be:

```
where c.Categories.Any(x => categoryIds.Contains(x.Id))
```

Because the `companies` is equivalent to:

```
var companies=(
    from c in context.Companies
    where c.Categories.Any(x => categoryIds.Contains(x.Id))
    select c
    ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> categoryIds = new List<int>() {123, 3, 5858, 23};    
List<company> companies = (from c in context.Companies
                           where categoryIds.Contains(c.Categories)
                           select c).ToList();  //I would add .ToList() since List<company>
```

This should work

If your list is really only 4 ints, then you could also do something like

```
where c.Categories == 123 || c.Categories == 3 || //ect.
```

Comment: c.Categories is not a list of int's, it's a list of Category objects.

Comment: no - "c" is a list of Companys, categoryIds is a List<Int> , this code is to get a List<Companies> where each Company object in the List<Companies> has an ID that mathes ID's in the List<Int>  , am I mistaken here? that seems what your question asked

Comment: each company has a list of categories attached to it. and from this list of categories (c.Categories) (which all have a CategoryId) at least one has to match with one of the id's from the list categoryIds

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as familiar with comprehension syntax as I used to be, but assuming the category field is named **CategoryId**, I believe the lambda version is:

```
var companies = dc.Companies
    .Where(c => categoryIds.Contains(c.CategoryId))
```

Comment: The point is, i don't have one CategoryId on my company object, but a list of categories. So have to match 2 lists.

Comment: The where expression returns true if any of the company category IDs matches any of the category IDs in the list. Based on your original query, it looks like you're trying to get a list of companies.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your problem i whould check the (DB)Category Table agaist the Category List. and then fetch all companies who are members is the Category table.

```
List<int> categoryIds = new List<int>() {123, 3, 5858, 23};    
List<company> companies = (from c in context.Companies
                           from b in context.Categories //Asuming there is a index table of some sort
                           where categoryIds.Contains(b.CatID) && c.companyID == b.companyID
                           select c).ToList();
```